# Signing-in Android to AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I try to connect sample app to my `Cognito` (user pool) on `AWS`. I follow that instruction:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

I am able to create (`sign up`) new users (I can see them in my user pool ) but when try to sign in Error message (`Sign-in Failed Error`) occurs on my phone. `Password` and `username` are correct.

I though it might be problem with libraries, so I changed it a bit. The code with dependencies and the error is attached below:

[code + error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRz4v.png)

Comment: What version of SDK you are using?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. I downloaded SKD v.2.2.18, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/146

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have diffrent error message:

com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo E/App Error: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Error (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace? And some code samples?

Comment: further, can you clear your app data before trying again?

Comment: Whole code is available on that link: 

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

All i changed is Pool_ID and so on. Error message is in the picture above.

Comment: I am not seeing a full stack trace on the link you provided.